# concatenate string inside a select statement

Tags: sql-server

Am new to sql server and would like your help. I have two tables `ProductCategory`- which has two fields `CategoryID and CategoryName`- and `Products` tables which has five fields `ProductID,ProductName,CategoryID,Price` and `Status`. What query should i use that will display the `ProductID,ProductName,Price,Status,ProductCategory` (Which Should be the `CategoryID,CategoryName` concatenated from the `CategoryTable`)

I have tried

```
SELECT ProductID,
       ProductName,
(
    SELECT CONCAT(CategoryID, CategoryName)
    FROM Category
) AS ProductCategory
FROM Items;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use joins in query as follows,

```
SELECT P.ProductID, P.ProductName, 
       CONCAT(P.CategoryID, C.CategoryName) AS ProductCategory
FROM Product P
     INNER JOIN ProductCategory C ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID;
```